# Get Current home screen wallpaper on IOS device

Tags: ios, cocoa

I know it is **not** possible to set the home screen wallpaper without user interaction on IOS device, but is it possible to get any information about what wallpaper is currently being used ? The reason being I have a requirement to try an mimic the home screen as far as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as far as I know that information is not available.

Also, be careful trying to mimic the home screen. There are warnings about doing that kind of thing in [Apple's Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

Comment: I believe you can only read the wallpaper on a jailbroken device

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I thought that may be the case.  As to the  Apple guidelines issue that wont be a problem as it is enterprise distribution only